# How to register a QueryExecuterFactory in jasper reports in java

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I implemented JRQueryExecuter and want to use it in a report. Using iReport I managed to register and use the executer.

Now I want to use it in a java application, but I can't find any resources how to register the factory.

I thought it's enough to have the implementation in the classpath, but I get the following exception:

```
Caused by: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: No query executer factory class registered for tmql queries.
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.query.DefaultQueryExecuterFactoryBundle.getQueryExecuterFactory(DefaultQueryExecuterFactoryBundle.java:80)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRQueryExecuterUtils.getQueryExecuterFactory(JRQueryExecuterUtils.java:57)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JRDesignDataset.queryLanguageChanged(JRDesignDataset.java:1006)
```

Can anybody give me a hint?

regards
Hannes

Answer (score 3):

Using jasperreports 5.2.0, you need to:

1. Create a custom `YourCustomExecuterFactory` implementing `QueryExecuterFactory` class.
2. Make your new `YourCustomExecuterFactory` use your custom `JRQueryExecuter` implementing method `QueryExecuterFactory.createQueryExecuter(..)`
3. Map the new language (tmql?) to your custom factory. In your `jasperresports.properties` set this property: `net.sf.jasperreports.query.executer.factory.tmql=your.package.YourCustomExecuterFactory`

Hope this helps to somebody.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation suggests to set a property:

```
JasperReport jasperReport = <...>
jasperReport.setProperty(JRQueryExecuterFactory.QUERY_EXECUTER_FACTORY_PREFIX + "<query language>", "<value>");
```

Does that work?

Answer (score 1):

Set the property before calling JasperCompileManager.

Example below using plsql query language:

```
JRProperties.setProperty(QueryExecuterFactory.QUERY_EXECUTER_FACTORY_PREFIX+"plsql"
                            ,"com.jaspersoft.jrx.query.PlSqlQueryExecuterFactory");
JasperReport jasperReport =
            JasperCompileManager.compileReport(sourceFile);
```

Comment: JRProperties is deprecated in Jasper Reports v6.1.0 and above - Is there any example how to do the same with jasperreports v6.8.0 ?

Comment: using JRPropertiesUtil how can we set the plsql query ?